# How to use nextJS with typescript and redux-saga?

Tags: typescript, next.js, redux-saga

I am currently working on a simple project using NextJS with typescript and redux-saga
and I am getting AN ERROR and it freaks me out so much.
I tried implementing ANY type to /store/index, /reducer/index but i am still getting another error.
Here is the error when I am using  wrapper.getStaticProps

[Here is the pic of the type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkQ6C.png)

and Here are my codes

**/_app.tx**

```js
import '../styles/globals.css';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import wrapper from '../store/configure';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

**/index.tsx**  => here is the file that i get type error using getStaticProps.

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import LandingPage from './LandingPage';
import wrapper from '../store/configure';
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <Layout title="LandingPage">
            <LandingPage />
        </Layout>
    );
}

export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(async ({store}) => {
// here I get type problem with (async ({store}) => ....
  await store.sagaTask?.toPromise();
});
```

**/reducer/index.ts**

```
import { RootStateInterface } from './../interface/iRootState';
import { AnyAction, combineReducers, Reducer } from 'redux';
import user from './user';

// export interface State {
//  user: IUserReducerState;
// }

const rootReducer: Reducer<RootStateInterface, AnyAction> =
    combineReducers<RootStateInterface>({
        user,
    });
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export default rootReducer;
```

**/store/configure.ts**

```
import { createWrapper, MakeStore } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore, Store, AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import createSagaMiddleware, { Task } from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from '../reducer';
import rootSaga from '../sagas';

const configureStore = () => {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];
    const enhancer =
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)) 
            : composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)); 
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, enhancer);
    store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    return store;
};

const wrapper = createWrapper(configureStore, {
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development', 
});

export default wrapper;
```

[fullscreen of the /page/index.tsx and err log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTme7.png)

I tried everything that I can do and now I'm stuck here.
thank you if you can share your great knowledge with me.

Just in case if you need all files

https://github.com/Gimoring/Petpairs/tree/Errors

or frontDev branch if needed.

Comment: For the first part you need to do: `createWrapper<AppState>(...)` in `store/configure.ts`, where `AppState` is the type that you want instead of `any` in `Store<any, AnyAction>` -- Refer this project for reference: https://github.com/edshav/next-redux-saga-typescript

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work for me. after changing the code like you mentioned
````
wrapper = createWrapper<IUserState>(configureStore, .....);
````
I have the following Error



Type 'IUserState' does not satisfy the constraint 'Store<any, AnyAction>'.
  Type 'IUserState' is missing the following properties from type 'Store<any, AnyAction>': dispatch, getState, subscribe, replaceReducer, [Symbol.observable]